# Duplicate Records within CRM

Tags: c#, duplicates, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

we recently had a migration project that went badly wrong and we now have 1000's of duplicate records. The business has been working with them which has made the issue worse as we now have records that have the same name and address but could have different contact information. A small number are exact duplicates. we have started the panful process of manually merging the records but this is very slow. Can anyone suggest another way of tackling the problem please?

Comment: If the migration was performed using the Bulk Import and CSV files, you can delete all records that were imported per that particular job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Arun Vinoth's answer, you might want to see what you can leverage with out-of-box [duplicate detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/sample-enable-duplicate-detection-and-retrieve-duplicates) to get sets of duplicates to apply the merge automation to.

Alternatively you can build your own dupe detection to match records on the various fields where you know dupes exist. I've done similar things to compare records across systems, including creating match codes to mimic how Microsoft does their dupe detection in CRM.

For example, a contact's match codes might be
1. the email address
2. the first name, last name, and company concatenated together without spaces.

If you need to match Companies, you can implement the an algorithm like Scribe's [stripcompany](https://help.scribesoft.com/scribeinsight/en/Subsystems/Insight/formulas/functions/stripcompany.htm) to generate matchcodes based on company names.

Since this seems like a huge problem you may want to consider drastic solutions like deactivating the entire polluted data set and redoing the data import clean, then finding any of the deactivated records that got touched in the interim to merge them, then deleting the entire polluted (deactivated) data set.

Bottom line, all paths seem to lead to major headaches and the only consolation is that you get to choose which path to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a console app quickly to merge them & refer the MSDN sample code for the same.

[Sample: Merge two records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-merge-two-records)

```
            // Create the target for the request.
            EntityReference target = new EntityReference();

            // Id is the GUID of the account that is being merged into.
            // LogicalName is the type of the entity being merged to, as a string
            target.Id = _account1Id;
            target.LogicalName = Account.EntityLogicalName;

            // Create the request.
            MergeRequest merge = new MergeRequest();
            // SubordinateId is the GUID of the account merging.
            merge.SubordinateId = _account2Id;
            merge.Target = target;
            merge.PerformParentingChecks = false;

            // Execute the request.
            MergeResponse merged = (MergeResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(merge);
```

> When merging two records, you specify one record as the master record, and Microsoft Dynamics CRM treats the other record as the child record or subordinate record. It will deactivate the child record and copies all of the related records (such as activities, contacts, addresses, cases, notes, and opportunities) to the master record.

[Read more](https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/merge-two-accounts-using-c-in-dynamics-crm-2011/)